# Collect data from a databound gridview and add it into a sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

First of all, i would like to point out that i am not that very experienced in VB.

This is how my program currently works:
I have 3 buttons, Sales, rent and courses. When i press each one of them, the datagridview1 gets populated with the respected products.

When datagridview1 is populated, i can select each product and copy them over to datagridview2 with the click of a button. That way the datagridview2 works as a "shopping cart".

What i want next, is when i press the "submit order" button, the query collects the data in the different "shopping cart" columns, and insert it into MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code to populate datagridview1:

```
Dim sporring As String
sporring = "SELECT * FROM TC_Utleie ORDER BY utleie_navn;"
Dim sqladapter As New MysqlDataAdapter
Dim comm2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sporring, tilkobling)
Dim ds AS New DataSet()

sqladapter.SelectCommand = comm2
sqladapter.fill(ds)
dgv.datasource = ds.tables(0)
```

This is my code to copy over the selected rows from datagridview1 to datagridview2:

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn in dgv.columns
 dgv2.columns.add(DirectCast(col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
Next
For rowindex As Integer = 0 To (dgv.SelectedRows.count -1)
 dgv2.rows.add(dgv.SelectedRows(rowindex).Cells.Cast(Of DatagridViewCell).Select(Function(c)c.value).ToArray)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

parameters.addwithvalue("@example1", row.cells(0).value)